# Наследование в генеалогическом

Tags: логика

Условие:

Даны два элемента в дереве. Определите, является ли один из них потомком другого.

Во входных данных записано дерево в том же формате, что и в предыдущей задаче Далее идет число запросов K. В каждой из следующих K строк, содержатся имена двух элементов дерева.

Для каждого такого запроса выведите одно из трех чисел: 1, если первый элемент является предком второго, 2, если второй является предком первого или 0, если ни один из них не является предком другого.

Ввод(пример):

9
Alexei Peter_I
Anna Peter_I
Elizabeth Peter_I
Peter_II Alexei
Peter_III Anna
Paul_I Peter_III
Alexander_I Paul_I
Nicholaus_I Paul_I

3
Anna Nicholaus_I
Peter_II Peter_I
Alexei Paul_I

Вывод:
1 2 0
Примечение:
Программа получает на вход число элементов в генеалогическом древе N. Далее следует N−1 строка, задающие родителя для каждого элемента древа, кроме родоначальника. Каждая строка имеет вид имя_потомка имя_родителя

Немогу понять почему такой вывод, и вроде как один предок - один потомок тут не получается. Был бы рад если бы кто-то смог объяснить как это работает

Answer (score 0):

если построить общее дерево для всей семьи, то получится, что Peter_I - родоначальник (уровень 0), его дети - Alexei Anna Elizabeth (уровень 1) и т.д
Anna является прородителем для Nicholaus_I - поэтому 1, Peter_II - потомок Peter_I - поэтому 2, Alexei никем не является Paul_I по прямой линии - поэтому 0.